# how to allow a multiselect this bootstrap dropdown code?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to allow multiselect in this bootstrap dropdown?. because this one is a dropdown menu that consists of a ul and li element..it's not a select element that I can just add 'multiple'...so how ?

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left dropdown-custom-quicklook">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-filter"></i> Filter By Quick Look</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right keep-open-on-click" role="menu">
         <?php
              foreach($quicklook as $look){
                 echo '<li><a href="">'.$look.'</a></li>';
              }
         ?>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://www.iminfo.in/post/bootstrap-multiselect-checkbox-list-dropdown-jquery , http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: how bout without using a plugin? is it not possible?

Comment: Instead of ul can you not use select tag? That will give you an easy option for multi select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the bootstrap-select.js thing to make it work